# Display folder selection dialog in Visual C++ 6

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to allow user to click a "Browse" button and display a folder selection dialog to allow user to select a folder on user's HDD. How do I do it? The closest control I could find in VC++ 6 is the dialog to browse file name

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [this class from codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2024/CFolderDialog-Selecting-Folders), which is a wrapper for `SHBrowseForFolder`. It provides an interface similar to that of `CFileDialog`:

```
CFolderDialog dlg(sTitle, sInitialPath, pParentWnd, nFlags);

if(dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
    CString sSelectedFolder = dlg.GetFolderPath();

    // Whatever
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Look at [`SHBrowseForFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762115%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which allows you to display the standard Windows "Select Folder" dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MFC try this

```
    char szFilters[]= "Text Files (*.NC)|*.NC|Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*||";

// Create an Open dialog; the default file name extension is ".my".

CFileDialog fileDlg (TRUE, "txt", "*.txt",    
      OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST| OFN_HIDEREADONLY, szFilters, this);


if( fileDlg.DoModal ()==IDOK )    
        CString m_strPathname = fileDlg.GetPathName();
```